# animateLayoutChanges has no effect

Tags: android, android-layout, animation, android-animation

also tried

```
setLayoutTransition(new LayoutTransition());
```

and it has also no effect for me. What could cause layout-animations to not work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make sure animations are enabled on the device and not disabled ( e.g. for espresso UI-Testing .. )

Answer (score 0):

Go to the Developer Options of your device, make transition animations enabled. And the animateLayoutChanges will be effect.